# Android. Catch application exit by Home click

Tags: android, workflow

I have an issue with identifying return to application after it was left using Home click.

The main purpose of this is to define when do I have to display to user Type Password dialog.

So, let's imaging such workflow, User works in application and decides to see what's the weather tomorrow. The User clicks Home button and is transfered to desktop. Now he goes back to My application. At this point we have to verify that our User is still the right one User by proposing him to type password.

How can I identify this condition here? (returning after leaving by Home click)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`android:stateNotNeeded`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#state) to `true` within `AndroidManifest.xml` for that activity.

Comment: Could you elaborate how? Thanks!